# What is the recommended fs.file-max value on redhat7

Tags: centos7, kernel, rhel7

How to calculate fs.file-max? what is the recommended value for rhel-7 and how to calculate the correct value?

Comment: What is the application type that is running on your machine and what are the hardware specifications?

Comment: How long is a piece of string? You make it as large as you need it.

Answer (score 2):

You can increase it to as much as you want or need, as long as you have enough  memory available and free CPU cycles.

Fedora 32 64bit has as default `fs.file-max = 9223372036854775807`

Comment: What is the math behind that large number?

Comment: it is just the default that is coming with Fedora 32 kernel. It is the maximum 64 bit integer: 2⁶³−1.

Comment: See also: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/a8b627aaed409a15260c25988970c795bf963812